# Solarized Dark + Gnome Terminal + Vim + Vim-Airline

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal, solarized

I installed the solarized dark theme for gnome terminal using https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized and then with [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) installed https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized. I added these lines to my `.vimrc`:

```
try
  " Solarized options
  let g:solarized_term = 1
  colorscheme solarized
catch                                                                         
endtry

set background=dark
```

I am also using https://github.com/bling/vim-airline installed using Vundle.

The problem is that in Normal mode vim-airline doesn't look great (text is very hard to read):

[image: Vim Ubuntu]

On my Mac with virtually the same setup it looks perfectly fine:

[image: Vim OSX]

How do I get vim on my Gnome Terminal to look like it does on my Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with terminator terminal.

Add following to `.vimrc` worked for me!

```
let &t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too!

-> I installed:
https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes.git

-> Then, I added this to my .vimrc:
let g:airline_theme = 'base16_solarized'

It becomes just like your Mac ;)